# Add Class to Wordpress gallery attachment via ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a class to images (Attachments) in a Wordpress Gallery (btw. strange that it is not possible by default), to make the possibility to have them at fullwidth in a Masonry Gallery. I set up ACF with a checkbox that can be ticked for this option, and generating field "fullwidth"
The problem I have is that I can't get to work the wp filter for the attachment image to inject the class to the appropriate place - the  level of the generated gallery code.

It should be:

```
<div id="gallery-2" class="gallery galleryid-45 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-large" >

  <dl class="gallery-item fullwidth">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
      <img width="700" height="467" src="xy.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large">
</dt></dl>

  <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <img width="700" height="525" src="xyz" class="attachment-large size-large" >
</dt></dl>

</div>
```

I use this code in my functions.php

```
function addclass_gallery_img_atts( $atts, $attachment ) {

if( get_field('fullwidth') ) {
    $fullwidth = get_field( "fullwidth" );
    $atts['class'] = $fullwidth;
}    
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'addclass_gallery_img_atts', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: what does get_field('fullwidth') return? if it is a checkbox, then it returns bool `true` or `false`  - meaning, that you are trying to push a boolean as a classname?

Comment: mby something like `if(get_field('fullwidth') == true){ $classname = 'fullWidth'; } else { $classname = ""; } $atts['class'] = $classname;`

Comment: Or you know - correctly written etc.

Comment: Oh, silly me, it is indeed a boolean... Checking the documentation it is 0 or 1 depending on the state. I wrote this code, 
if ( get_field('fullwidth') == 1 ){ 
 $classname = 'fullwidth'; 
} else { 
 $classname = ""; 
} 

$atts['class'] = $classname;
 
But it still doesn't work... Isn't it the problem that it can't take out the values of the attachment in generated the_content()? 
Also, the problem is that it adds class to the img, and not the dl. Can it be controlled somehow?

Comment: I think what I need is the post_gallery function, but can't find any useful info how to hook in to it to change the style :-(

Comment: Don't know - you might need to access the global post, since you need an ACF field, if that is not found then it would just return

Comment: also - I think that it should be `$atts['class'] .= ' fullwidth'; ` - so you don't overwrite the previous classes

Comment: If this is generated in the content - you can't use this filter though

Comment: There is a guide here, on how to use the content filter, to change the image markups for you : https://jhtechservices.com/changing-your-image-markup-in-wordpress/

Comment: Filter 3 might be excatly what you are looking for, in the guide

Comment: Thanks, but I think this approach was not correct for many reasons (ACF not triggering and targeting img tag and not the dl wrapper). I started another thread with the different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851107/hook-in-to-post-gallery-function-to-change-the-styles-of-gallery