# Hook in to post_gallery function to change the styles of gallery

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem that drives me mad, and can't find a solution to it in the documentation...
I want to hook in to Wordpress' post_gallery function to add a Class to the dl element that wraps the WP generated gallery individual images. By this I want to have the option to have full width images that can be controlled in the Attachments window of WP Media via ACF switch

```
if ( get_field('fullwidth') == 1 ){ 
    $classname = 'fullwidth'; 
} else { 
    $classname = ""; 
}
```

Also setting the img "src" to the Large for these fullwidth images would come handy, so the page-load is not too slow.

Do I need to rewrite the whole gallery generating code from here?
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php

Can it be done via this method at all, or should I somehow try to hook in to the_content? But also for that method, I didn't find any info in regard how galleries are generated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to add a Class to the dl element that wraps the WP generated gallery individual images

Instead of that, why don't you — using the Text/HTML editor — add the gallery like this:

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    [gallery ... /]
</div>
```

(the three dots indicates the Shortcode parameters such as `ids`, `size`, and `link`)

And write some CSS code similar to:

```
.fullwidth .gallery-item {
    /* Add styles for the DL (or FIGURE for HTML5-supported themes) element that wraps the gallery image and caption. */
}

    .fullwidth .gallery-icon {
        /* Add styles for the DT (or DIV for HTML5-supported themes) element that wraps the gallery image. */
    }

    .fullwidth .gallery-caption {
        /* Add styles for the DD (or FIGCAPTION for HTML5-supported themes) element that wraps the gallery caption. */
    }
```

[EDIT] Below is **a custom Shortcode**; used the exact same way you'd use the default `[gallery]` Shortcode.

Add these to the theme's *functions.php* file:

```
/**
 * @param array $attr
 * @param WP_Post $attachment
 */
function gallery_shortcode2_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ) {
    // Name of the custom field. (ACF)
    $field_name = 'fullwidth';

    if ( get_field( $field_name, $attachment->ID ) ) {
        $attr['data-gallery-layout'] = 'full-width';
    }

    return $attr;
}

add_shortcode( 'gallery2', 'gallery_shortcode2' );
function gallery_shortcode2( $attr ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'itemtag' => 'figure',       // I'm assuming we'll always be using HTML5-supported themes..
        'fwclass' => 'fullwidth',    // The CSS class applied to items with, well, full-width layout.
        'size'    => 'medium_large', // You may change the default value; to "large", "custom", etc.
    ), $attr );

    // Don't modify anything below unless you're 100% sure of what you're doing. =)

    $itemtag = tag_escape( $atts['itemtag'] );
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) ) {
        $itemtag = 'dl';
    }

    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'gallery_shortcode2_image_attributes', 10, 2 );
    $output = gallery_shortcode( array_merge( $attr, $atts ) );
    $output2 = '';
    remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'gallery_shortcode2_image_attributes', 10, 2 );

    $_tag = '<' . preg_quote( $itemtag ) . ' class=\'gallery-item\'>';
    $arr = preg_split( "/($_tag)/", $output, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    for ( $i = 0, $j = 1; $i < count( $arr ); $i++, $j++ ) {
        if ( $_tag === $arr[ $i ] && isset( $arr[ $j ] ) ) {
            $class = 'gallery-item';
            if ( preg_match( '/<img (.*?) data-gallery-layout="full-width"/', $arr[ $j ] ) ) {
                $class .= ' ' . $atts['fwclass'];
            }

            $output2 .= '<' . $itemtag . ' class=\'' . esc_attr( $class ) . '\'>';
        } else {
            $output2 .= $arr[ $i ];
        }
    }
    unset( $output, $arr );

    return $output2;
}
```

And use `[gallery2]` instead of `[gallery]`; same arguments (e.g. `ids` and `size`), but with one extra argument for `[gallery2]`, which is `fwclass`. (Refer to the `gallery_shortcode()` function for details on that argument.)

Hopefully `[gallery2]` works for you, like it did for me.

**NOTE:** Use `[gallery2]` *only if* you want to add a custom CSS `class` to the individual gallery item element (i.e. `.gallery-item`). Otherwise, use the default Shortcode — `[gallery]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use the fullwidth only on some of the images, that are set like that from the ACF true/false switch – so the images that have false are 48%, and true 96% (both set in css via classes). Unfortunately jQuery trickery is not possible, because I use Masonry, and it messes up the layout.

Comment: Great, works like a charm! Thank you! One last thing though, how can I strip out the link <a href=""> from the images, so the don't link to the attachment?

Comment: Add `link="none"` to the Shortcode tag. E.g. `[gallery2 ids="1,2,3" link="none" /]`.

Comment: Also, please don't forget to mark this question as answered.. unless you need further assistance on my answer. Thanks. =)

Comment: Oh, silly me, that can indeed be set-up from the gallery page.

Comment: Yes, [indeed](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_WordPress_Gallery#Step_4_.E2.80.93_Edit_Your_Gallery) =) — see the "Link To" option on [this image](https://codex.wordpress.org/File:edit-gallery-drag.png).

Comment: Thanks, it was a huge help you set me up the code. Big thumbs up!